# how to display a images from local disk?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to display a images from local disk as well as from database

normally i used like

```
<img src="/images/ome.jpg">
```

if above image is already copied to the application, then only displayed

I like to get a image from db and local drive

Comment: You can not delete from 2 tables at same time, but you can ether use magic tables (google them) or do the join and insert those joined rows into temp table and then use it as reference for delete

Comment: You must define two deletes operations

Comment: you cannot delete two tables at a same time.

Comment: sorry i changed error

Comment: see above?? help me friends

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to really be looking for is a cascading delete foreign key constraint.  Assuming that `Emp_Id` is the primary key in `EmpProof`, you can define:

```
alter table EmpQuali add constraint fk_empquali_empid
    foreign key (emp_id) references empproof (emp_id)
        on delete cascade;
```

Then when you delete from `EmpProof`, corresponding rows will be deleted from `EmpQuali`:

```
DELETE FROM EmpProof WHERE EmpProof.Emp_id = 2;
```

Comment: it will show like Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'constraint'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I don't know as you call your id field):

```
CREATE TABLE #app (id_empproof int , id_empquali int)

INSERT INTO #app
SELECT EmpProof.Emp_id, EmpQuali.emp_id
FROM EmpProof
INNER JOIN EmpQuali  
on EmpProof.Emp_id= EmpQuali.Emp_id Where EmpProof.Emp_id = 2
```

So you can write two deletes operations, as follow:

```
DELETE FROM EmpProof
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
FROM #app a
WHERE a.empproof_id = empproof.emp_id)

DELETE FROM EmpQuali
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
FROM #app a
WHERE a.empquali_id = empquali.emp_id)
```